# SQLAlchemy expects an object, but finds a Table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently starting with sqlalchemy. In my current project I have to do some part with Flask and some other part from the command line. The part about flask is running fine, interfacing with sqlalchemy and all, but the commandline part is not.

The error I'm getting is

```
ArgumentError("Class object expected, got 'Table('documentos', 
 MetaData(bind=Engine(postgresql://user:password@localhost/clasificador)), 
 Column('id', Integer(), table=<documentos>, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
 Column('nombre', String(length=248), table=<documentos>), schema=None)'.",)
```

I've tried my luck with google and reading declarative sqlalchemy, but I can't find what could be the problem. The code in the module is:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from db import engine,Base
#some other code
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
doc = modelos.documento.Documento(os.path.basename(nelto))
session.add(doc) #here fails
session.remove()
```

db is the module where I have the common code for sqlalchemy. most of it comes from flask documentation, and db_session is used only for flask, I made a different session for the other module.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

sqldebug=True 

engine = create_engine( 
    'postgresql://user:passwd@localhost/clasificador',
    convert_unicode=True,
    echo=sqldebug)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Finally, here is the "documento" module, although I doubt the problem is here.
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from db import Base

```
class Documento(Base):
    '''Clase definiendo los documentos'''
    __tablename__ = "documentos"

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True) 
    nombre = Column(String(248))

    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre             

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Documento %r>' % self.nombre
```

Some of the comments/names are in spanish, but I think you can safely ignore them, if it's necessary I'll do the translations

Following Lafada's code I've created another file with just:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from modelos.documento import Documento
from db import Base, engine
import os

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
doc = Documento(os.path.basename('/tmp/test.py')) #here fails
session.add(doc) 
session.commit()
```

and it runs just fine. The only difference I can spot is how the session is created, I've modified that as well in my original code, but it keeps getting the same error.

I found the culprit, it wasn't on the code I'm showing, but in a different class which was trying to create a relationship with it but linking to the table instead of the object. Until i tried several other things I couldn't trace it to the real problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried your code on mysql (I Dont have postgress in my pc :(). I am putting that code here please check that because that is working fine for me.

```
#filename: /tmp/test.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessio

nmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import os

sqldebug=True 

engine = create_engine('mysql://test:test@localhost/test1', 
            convert_unicode=True,
            echo=sqldebug)

#create_engine( 
#           'postgresql://user:passwd@localhost/clasificador',
#           convert_unicode=True,
#           echo=sqldebug)

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class Documento(Base):
    '''Clase definiendo los documentos'''
    __tablename__ = "documentos"

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String(248))

    def __init__(self,nombre):         
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Documento %r>' % self.nombre

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
#some other code
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
doc = Documento(os.path.basename('/tmp/test.py'))
session.add(doc) #here fails
session.commit()
```

Output log

```
In [11]: ed /tmp/test.py
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
2011-11-18 08:48:41,254 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,254 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,259 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%%'
2011-11-18 08:48:41,259 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,290 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2011-11-18 08:48:41,290 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,320 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW COLLATION
2011-11-18 08:48:41,320 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,339 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2011-11-18 08:48:41,339 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,343 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine DESCRIBE `documentos`
2011-11-18 08:48:41,343 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,389 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
2011-11-18 08:48:41,391 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE documentos (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    nombre VARCHAR(248), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2011-11-18 08:48:41,391 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2011-11-18 08:48:41,683 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2011-11-18 08:48:41,698 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2011-11-18 08:48:41,700 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO documentos (nombre) VALUES (%s)
2011-11-18 08:48:41,700 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('test.py',)
2011-11-18 08:48:41,701 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

As per log, this code will add one new record in db. If you have any other query then its good if I help you in that :)

Comment: This is weird, I've run your code (changing it to postgres) and it runs fine, I've had rearranged it to just the following and it still runs (whith the imports to other parts of my code)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    doc = Documento(os.path.basename('/tmp/test.py'))
    session.add(doc) #here fails
    session.commit()

Comment: I've modified the original question to add the new code, as it can't be seen properly here

Comment: I finally rewrote all the code and it worked, It's almost the same in different files.
So I award you the response as I would have never tried to write it in another file (and shouldn't be a solution)

Answer (score 29):

I have seen that error before if I forget that `ForeignKey()` takes the name of a database table-and-field but that `relationship()` takes the name of an ORM class instead. That is, I sometimes write:

```
movie_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('movie.id'))
movie = relationship('movie')  # WRONG!
# Exception: "SQLAlchemy expects to find an object…"
```

What I should instead be writing, assuming that `movie` is the name of the database table (not that SQL pays attention to table name capitalization!) and that `Movie` is the name of my Python ORM class, is:

```
movie_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('movie.id'))
movie = relationship('Movie')  # Works!
```

Comment: Wow, + a billion for this.  I did that exact thing.  This inconsistency is kind of terrible.

Comment: One might think that sqlalchemy could emit a better error message for that kind of mistake. In fact, having been bitten by this today, I'll post a bug report.

Comment: I had this problem two weeks ago, forgot about it, and then ran into it just now. Makes me feel like sideshow bob stepping on rakes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with sqlalchemy and its declarative format but one thing that I think is not correct is you are overwriting the `init` method without calling the its parent's class (here it is `Base`).

Remove the `init` or call `Base.init(self)`.

Comment: For that part, I followed the tutorial from [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlalchemy/) and it works when I use flask, without complains.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok but remember that Flask could be adding something in order to let you define that init method. In pure python+sqlalchemy that may not work!

Comment: in any other case I'd say you are most likely correct, but even the sqlalchemy tutorial does it this way, so I was confident that was not the problem. Thank you for pointing it anyway :)